# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3})=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Use the definition of the limit of a sequence to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3})=\frac{1}{2}$.

We have
$$\begin{align} 
\left|\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}-\frac{1}{2}\right| & =\left|\frac{2n^2-2-2n^2-3}{2(2n^2+3)}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{-5}{2(2n^2+3)}\right|\\
&= \frac{5}{2(2n^2+3)} \\
&<\frac{5}{4n^2},
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{5}{4n^2}<\epsilon \iff \frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{4 \epsilon}{5} \iff n>\sqrt{\frac{5}{4\epsilon}}$$

We choose $n_0=\left[\sqrt{\frac{5}{4\epsilon}} \right]+1$, Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

> Let $(x_n)=\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> a) Use the definition of the limit to show that $\lim(x_n)=0$.

$|\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}-0|=\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow ln(n+1) > \epsilon  \Leftrightarrow n> e^{\epsilon} -1$

We choose $n_0=\left[ e^\epsilon -1 \right]+1$, Then $\lim(x_n)=0$.

> b) Find specific value of $n_0 (\epsilon)$ as required in definition of limit for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.

$n_0=\left[\sqrt{e}-1\right]+1$

Is that true, please?

Comment: In your second exercise, you should have $\ln(n+1)>1/\epsilon$.

Comment: You are only showing the work in finding an $n_0$. The actual proof should look like "Let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $n_0 =$ ____. Then if $n>n_0$ .... work ... $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$. QED"

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales You are right. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DavidPeterson Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the *definition* of a limit at infinity, you should include a few more references to the definition in the proof:

Prove: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there is a positive integer $n_0$ such that if $n>n_0$ then $\left|\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\epsilon$

Then proceed with the steps which you have given.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

For a) We have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2(1-\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2(2+\frac{3}{n^2})}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}{2+\frac{3}{n^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$

For b) basically the same,meaning $ln$ is monotone so for $n\rightarrow \infty$ it follows that $\ln(n)\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry I forget to write "by the definition".

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. However it seems you may have overcomplicated it.

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}\right) & = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}{2+\frac{3}{n^2}}\right)\\
\end{align}

Now use the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^k}\right)=0$, where $k$ is any positive integer.

Hence 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}{2+\frac{3}{n^2}}\right) & = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1-0}{2+0}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry I forget to write "by the definition".